# How do I make each new output appear in a new box?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like for every different item inputted to be outputted in a new box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
```

Form to get the input

```
<form id="form1">
    <input name="item" type="text" size="20">
</form>
```

Box that should be duplicated to hold the new input.

```
<div class="box">
    <p class="output"></p>
<div>


<button onclick="outputItem()">Add</button>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    function outputItem() {
        var x = document.getElementById("form1"); 
        item = x.elements.namedItem("item").value;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=item;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look into the `.clone()` DOM method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is even close to what you want, but give this a try:

```js
function outputItem() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 input"); 
  var box = document.querySelector('.box');
  box.innerHTML = '';
  els.forEach(
    function(el) {
      var newEl = document.createElement('div');
      newEl.innerHTML = el.value;
      box.appendChild(newEl);
    }
  );
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
    <input name="item" type="text" size="20" value="item"><br/>
    <input name="eggs" type="text" size="20" value="eggs"><br/>
    <input name="milk" type="text" size="20" value="milk"><br/>
    <input name="grains" type="text" size="20" value="grains"><br/>
    <input name="legumes" type="text" size="20" value="legumes"><br/>
</form>
<button onclick="outputItem()">Add</button>
<hr/>
<div class="box"></div>
```

This creates a new `<div>` for every input and copies the `.value` from the `<input>` into the new `<div>`. Then it adds the `<div>` into the output area.